# Why my SWF file is so big?

Tags: actionscript, flash

So I'm pretty experienced with OOP (I like to believe) and I just started with Flash CS5 and ActionScript.

I created a new empty file and added a button to it. Nothing else, no code at all.

I set in the publishing options the "Default linkage" option to "Merged into code" to see how big the download will be for those who are loading it for the first time without cache and the size turned out to be ~500KB which is a far cry from the ~20KB it is with the shared libraries option.

So, why is my file so big? I thought all the features I'm using are built in the flash player and no external libraries are required to load?

Also, is there a way to see what external files my swf depends on to run?

Comment: I removed the Flex tag since you aren't using Flex.

Comment: @Marty thanks for the link, but it doesn't answer any of my questions at all ;)

Comment: True, it might help me help you if you post a link to the SWF somewhere.

Comment: How did you add a button? Did you use the Flash IDE and drag a button from the components panel to the stage?

Comment: If you are compiling using the debug option the this will add a ton to the file size.

Answer (score 2):

If your button is the default Flex button (as opposed to creating your own using pure as3), then you're probably bringing in the the entire Flex lib. It's why I stopped using it :)